# How to get current user's custom information and show it on any screen?

Tags: acumatica

I had made a custom field 'warehouse' on User screen(SM201010), and saved some text in this field to the user 'user1'.

The question is when I login as the user1. How can I display the 'warehouse' field on any screen else?

I had try AccessInfo, but dont know how it works. Please help! Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AccessInfo contains basic information on the current user, but adding a custom field to the User screen will not add it as a member of AccessInfo.

If you added a custom field in a DAC Extension, you will need to fetch the User record, get its extension and then you can access this custom value.

Here are some links about extensions :

https://docref.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=3a427466-1925-4799-8fee-fe34a77021d0

https://docref.acumatica.com/Main.aspx?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=114ae5af-8667-4933-b53d-c4c8667c85ac

I highly suggest you complete the T300 certification class which teaches how to do customizations in Acumatica. It is available in our Open University

Comment: Thanks for replying! But how to know who is the current user? then I can fetch the User record. 'AccessInfo' can do this automatically.

Comment: Use Accessinfo.UserID